# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to en-US culture

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I added custom `JsonSerializerSettings` to ensure the date is always de-serialized to `en-US culture`.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                                { Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") });
```

However, This does not work for Hijri Calendar and date is still de-serialized in ar culture calendar.

Why? What am I missing here?

**Were T**

```
public partial class T
    {
    --------------------
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveEndDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> SourceDate { get; set; }
    -----------------
    }
```

**Json response**
{ ..... , "effectiveStartDate":"2018-01-02T00:00:00", .... }

**After deserialize**

15/04/39 12:00:00

**Whereas my expected is**

02/01/2018

Comment: Care to show us the JSON, and T?

Comment: Ideally, provide a [mcve]. It's not clear what you mean by "date is still de-serialized in ar culture calendar". (I *suspect* you're going by the output of DateTime.ToString in the debugger, but it's hard to know for sure.)

Comment: Hi John i updated my question. Sorry missed out in first attempt

Comment: `EffectiveStartDate` is a DateTime, which is just a number. What you're seeing is the debugger converting that number to a human-readable format for you. If you call `EffectiveStartDate.ToString("o")` you will see the correct ISO8601 date.

Comment: What? Seriously? It is not debugger converted value its deserialized value my friend. You know why it gave the value 15/04/39 12:00:00? Because the current culture is ar. So what i tried is to request JsonConverter to always use en-US

Comment: @immirza Read the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks (see **Notes to Callers** section)

Comment: @immirza I think you're the one misunderstanding. Is your machine set up for "ar" culture? If so, that's the format the debugger will show you the value. Once it becomes a DateTime it's nothing to do with the serializer.

Comment: Oh ok i misunderstood than thanks. So how i would bring it back en-US culture?

Comment: You can pass a culture to `ToString` (format provider). It depends how you're using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how the code will work. The deserialisation process will go something like this:

1. Create an instance of `T` (let's call it `x`).
2. Start to read the properties from the JSON, and find matching properties in `T`. Convert the JSON properties into C# variables, and add them to the correct property in `x`.
3. When we get to the `effectiveStartDate` property, it will deserialise the value into a DateTime object. In order to parse the string in the JSON, it references the `en-US` culture setting which you provided, in case the string shows the date in US format (e.g. mm/dd/yyyy). However, the date is in ISO format, which is unambiguous and easily readable by a computer without being told what to expect. So in fact the culture setting doesn't matter at all in this case.
4. Store the parsed date in a `DateTime` object. `DateTime` does not use a specific format internally - it just stores the date as a number. Formats are only used for serialising dates to strings, or showing them to humans.

Deserialisation is now complete and you have a regular C# object to use freely within your code.

Presumably you then try to read the `x.effectiveStartDate` value somewhere in your code, or via your debugger (you haven't shown us exactly what you're doing to view the date). Inevitably, since you want to view it, C# outputs the number stored within the DateTime object as a human-readable date string. Note that the deserialisation process has completed, and you are now back in the context of your application. Because of this, you see the date formatting according to the `ar` culture and its associated calendar style, because that's your application's culture. The `en-US` culture only applied to the deserialisation process, which has already finished.

If you want to display your date in a different format than the application culture, then you need to tell the application that explicitly. You can set a format via the `toString` method of `DateTime`, for instance, and/or temporarily change your culture settings via your code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ADyson mentioned above.

Taken from official [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx). A must read ariticle for every developer want to know more about DateTime

> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks
>   (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since
>   12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is
>   independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a
>   user interface element or when written to a file. The appearance of a
>   DateTime value is the result of a formatting operation. Formatting is
>   the process of converting a value to its string representation.
>   Because the appearance of date and time values is dependent on such
>   factors as culture, international standards, application requirements,
>   and personal preference, the DateTime structure offers a great deal of
>   flexibility in formatting date and time values through the overloads
>   of its ToString method. The default DateTime.ToString() method returns
>   the string representation of a date and time value using the current
>   culture's short date and long time pattern. The following example uses
>   the default DateTime.ToString() method to display the date and time
>   using the short date and long time pattern for the en-US culture, the
>   current culture on the computer on which the example was run.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));
// Displays 01/03/2008 07:00:00
  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx
```